# Django: Adding Permission to an Specific Model Instance

Tags: django, django-permissions

I am looking for the best way to implement user permissions to allow users to edit specific model instances.

For instance, I have such two models:

```
model RadioChannel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique= True)
    number = models.IntegerField( unique= True)

model ProgramSchedule(models.Model):
    channel = models.ForeignKey("RadioChannel")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique= True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
```

Now my Operators are my build-in Django users. I want to make groups for these users so that they can only add/remove/edit ProgramSchedules that are allowed. In addition I want to add groups to these users to the admin panel.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

You are looking for an object permission implementation. A good comparison is here:
http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/perms/

Shameless plug:
Heres my fork of a very popular per-object permission app: http://github.com/azizmb/django-authority

Comment: Sounds good ! Did you document also how to add permissions from python code ? That was something I kind of missed in the original version of the doc.

Answer (score 5):

If I am getting you correct, what you need to implement is called row level permissions in Django. Have a look at this if it helps. http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/RowLevelPermissionsDeveloper

Comment: This allows you to set the permissions on the row level i.e. a specific instance of the model.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using [Django Guardian](https://github.com/lukaszb/django-guardian) for object-level permissions.